# CSS Positioning, Vertically & Horizontally centering a DIV?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page, where there is a div in the middle of the page centered horizontally, not vertically, with 3 more divs inside of it which are centered vertically and horizontally with equal spacing. In order to achieve this I thought it would be best to create another div with no background colour, then using margin: auto on it, this div is centered in the main div, but I can't get the 3 other divs to center in that, it's like the margins aren't taking into account the parent element?

I have tried a few methods which say they should center my elements, but they do not work for me, so I thought it would be best if someone can explain to me how this effect can be achieved in CSS.

Here is a screenshot of the current situation (red div will be invisible in final design, coloured to help me): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTAqt.jpg

HTML Code:

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Title Placeholder</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
 
 <div id="title"></div>

 <div id="introdiv"></div>

 <div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>


</html>
```

CSS Code:

```css
html {
 background: ##6f7604;
 background-image: url("zenbg-1.png"), url("zenbg-2.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}


#title {

 background-color: rgba(83,188,255,0.6);
 min-height: 5%;
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;

}


#introdiv {

 background-color: rgba(255,207,76,0.9);
 min-height: 15%;
 width: 70%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 2.5%;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;

}


#wrapper {

 background-color: rgba(83,188,255,0.6);
 min-height: 65%;
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 2.5%;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;

}

#container {

 min-height: 10%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: red;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 6.5%;
}

.box {

 background-color: rgba(255,207,76,0.9);
 min-height: 40%;
 width: 20%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks for your help, if you need any more info, ask.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/w5qje0yy/

Comment: http://flexboxin5.com/ Check out flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `absolute` position and `transform` to align element `middle` and `center`. Example:

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
}

.center-h {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #555;
}

.center-vh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
}
.box:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="center-h">
    <div class="center-vh">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vertical-align: middle like this

```
.box {

    background-color: rgba(255,207,76,0.9);
    min-height: 40%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
}
```